# Custom styling for Javadocs within Eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, javadoc

I've discovered that I can add some CSS styling to Javadocs in Eclipse, to create some nice effects for the inline code hovers.

Sample javadoc:

```java
/**
 * <p>This is a general description of the class.<p>
 * 
 * <p>Here is a useful direct quote:</p>
 * 
 * <div style="background-color:white; border: 1px solid gray; margin: 1em 2.5em; padding: 0em 0.5em">
 *   <p>This quote has a list:</p>
 *   <ul>
 *     <li>Item 1</li>
 *     <li>Item 2</li>
 *   </ul>
 * </div>
 *
 */
public class SSCCE {

}
```

Sample result:
[image: Javadoc hover example]

I'd like to take advantage of this more in my code, but it would be much better if I could use something like `<div class="box">` instead of setting the style attribute manually, for the following reasons:

1. If I later decide to tweak the style, I might have to change hundreds of Javadoc comments
2. At the moment, I only care about the appearance within Eclipse.  However, if I ever export the Javadocs to HTML, I might want the HTML version to have a different style than the Eclipse version.

Is it possible to do this in Eclipse, perhaps with a plugin?

Comment: Perhaps not what you wanted, but you could compile the JavaDocs, set the stylesheet and then link the project to the correct location for reading the JavaDocs.

Comment: @TomCammann - great suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work, at least not in Eclipse 3.7.1.  Attaching the Javadoc lets me open it in the browser, but the Eclipse hovers don't use it.  I deleted the javadoc comment in the .java file, and the Eclipse hover shows empty, even though I can click "Open Attached in Browser" to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Through experimentation I discovered I could link to a stylesheet using a `<link>` tag with an `href` relative to the .java file location.  This does address issue #1 mentioned in the question, but personally I think it's too cumbersome and probably won't use it.  It also doesn't solve issue #2 (if anything, it makes it worse).

I'm still open to suggestions for better solutions!  I suspect though it would take an Eclipse plugin to fully achieve what I really want to do.

*[project-root]/src/org/foobar/Foo.java:*

```java
package org.foobar;

/**
 * <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../javadoc.css"/>
 * 
 * <p class="orange">Foo doc, in orange</p>
 */
public class Foo {

}
```

*[project-root]/javadoc.css*

```css
p.orange {
    color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think when you get to the part to export as styled JavaDoc, you can use this [Java tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html).
Also check this [book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0321246233/documenting-your-code-with-javadoc/ch15lev1sec5) which might help for specifying style sheets for javadoc in Eclipse.
And maybe you might also get to the point of creating your own doc generation plugin.